# GRASS GIS: how to define several variables in a loop without the command locals()?

Tags: python-2.7, splitting, loop, grass-7.0

I am working on a Python script in GRASS GIS and want define several variables in a loop. My simple loop is working, but I don't know how to integrate sevaral variables.

```
RG_koor=g.read_command("v.out.ascii", input="e_"+Nr_RG[i], fs=",", format="point")
zeil=RG_koor.split("\n") 
easting=[];northing=[]  # define northing and wasting koordinates, empty

for i in range(len(zeil)-1):
  zeile=[]  # define "zeile" for easting and northing coodinates
  zeile=zeil[i].split(",") #split the colums when the comma appears
  easting.append(float(zeile[0])) #easting, all values before the first comma
  northing.append(float(zeile[1])) #northing, all values before the second comma
```

I tried the command locals (), but I read, that it is not recomended.Do you have  an idea, how I could improve my script without using the command locals()? I only would like to generate the northing and easting values of several data in two different files. The upcoming code is working until the second .split. So, I still do not understand, why the second .plit does not work.

```
Nr_RG=["001","002","003","004","005"]
for i in range (len(Nr_RG)): 
    locals()["RG_koor{0}".format(i)] = g.read_command("v.out.ascii", input="e_"+Nr_RG[i], fs=",", format="point") 
    locals()["zeil{0}".format(i)] = locals()["RG_koor{0}".format(i)].split("\n")
    locals()["easting{0}".format(i)]=[];locals()["northing{0}".format(i)]=[]  # define northing and wasting koordinates, empty

    for i in range (len(locals()["zeil{0}".format(i)])):
        locals()["zeile{0}".format(i)]=[] # define "zeile" for easting and northing coodinate
    locals()["zeile{0}".format(i)] = locals()["zeil{0}".format(i)].split(",") #split the colums, when the comma appears
    locals()["easting{0}".format(i)].append(float(locals()["zeile{0}".format(i)][0])) #easting, all values before the first comma
    locals()["northing{0}".format(i)].append(float(locals()["zeile{0}".format(i)][1])) #northing, all values before the seocnd comma
```

Here are my outputs for the second command:

```
    Nr_RG=["001","002","003","004","005"]
for i in range (len(Nr_RG)):
    sqlite="""substr(cmt,1,4)='R"""+str(Nr_RG[i]+"'")
    print sqlite
    g.run_command("v.extract", overwrite=True, input="rec_RG", output="e_"+Nr_RG[i], where=sqlite)   
    locals()["RG_koor{0}".format(i)] = g.read_command("v.out.ascii", input="e_"+Nr_RG[i], fs=",", format="point") 
    locals()["zeil{0}".format(i)] = locals()["RG_koor{0}".format(i)].split("\n")
    locals()["easting{0}".format(i)]=[];locals()["northing{0}".format(i)]=[]

substr(cmt,1,4)='R001'
0
substr(cmt,1,4)='R002'
0
substr(cmt,1,4)='R003'
0
substr(cmt,1,4)='R004'
0
substr(cmt,1,4)='R005'
0
```

When i split the second time by using locals (), the command is not working.

```
 for i in range (len(Nr_RG)):
    locals()["zeile{0}".format(i)]=[] # define "zeile" for easting and northing coodinate
    locals()["zeile{0}".format(i)] = locals()["zeil{0}".format(i)].split("\n") 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 3, in <module>
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Comment: are you working with GRASS 7.x or GRASS 6.4.x ?

Comment: I am working with GRASS 7.0.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use the new possibilities of Python in GRASS 7.x: [PyGRASS](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/libpython/pygrass_index.html)

Your script with an example

```
RG_koor=grass.read_command("v.out.ascii", input="list_points", separator=",", format="point")
zeil=RG_koor.split("\n") 
easting=[];northing=[] 
for i in range(len(zeil)-1):
    zeile=[] 
    zeile=zeil[i].split(",") 
    easting.append(float(zeile[0]))
    northing.append(float(zeile[1]))
print northing
[125744.93437974, 123785.81230088, 123799.41731532, 122724.62117483, 125622.48924981, 123146.37662237]
print easting
[227192.86784828, 227764.27845461, 230498.88635635, 229764.21557678, 230648.54151515, 231750.54768451]
```

With [PyGRASS: Vector classes](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/libpython/pygrass_vector.html)

The script becomes:

```
zeil  = VectorTopo('list_of_points')
easting,northing = zip(*[(pt.x,pt.y) for pt in zeil])
```

Explications

```
from grass.pygrass.vector import VectorTopo
test  = VectorTopo('list_of_points')
test.exist()
True
test.is_open()
False
# open the layer
test.open(mode='r') # the result is a generator/iterator
for pt in test:
    print pt,
POINT(227192.867848 125744.934380) POINT(227764.278455 123785.812301) POINT(230498.886356 123799.417315) POINT(229764.215577 122724.621175) POINT(230648.541515 125622.489250) POINT(231750.547685 123146.376622)
# to return to the beginning, use rewind()
test.rewind()
easting = [pt.x for pt in test]
northing = [pt.y for pt in test]    
print northing
[125744.93437974199, 123785.81230088188, 123799.41731531841, 122724.62117483266, 125622.48924981322, 123146.37662236505]
print easting
[227192.86784827572, 227764.27845460994, 230498.88635635216, 229764.21557677962, 230648.54151515398, 231750.54768451277]
# and finally in one line
test.rewind()
easting,northing = zip(*[(pt.x,pt.y) for pt in test])
```

And you don't need to use `locals()` for the second part, simply use PyGRASS

Comment: Thanks for your help. Your Pygrass-script is working fine, but I still have the problem, that I don't know, how to integrate several variables into the scipt? I want to extract the easting and northing values for a lot of "test". Therefore I need to rename the variables in a loop, how can I do this without using locals()?

Comment: I don't know the `locals() ` command, I use PyGRASS now (look at  [vector attributes](http://wgbis.ces.iisc.ernet.in/grass/grass71/manuals/pygrass/vector_attributes.html))